# Tooltip with AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-tooltip

I am making an extension that highlights certain words and forms a tooltip. 
My application relies heavily on displaying the content of another webpage.
I am currently trying to use my tooltip with the AJAX tooltip example from tooltip.js which displays a video from Vimeo in the tooltip.

However, when I actually use the tooltip the video keeps buffering and messes up the webpage I used the extension on entirely - it superimposes half the webpage with nothing or another component of the webpage. Do you know any solution? Should I try something else?

Here's a link to the documentation and example I am using: http://www.tippedjs.com/documentation
Here's my code:

```
//this specifies the DOM element being tool-tiped in extension
Tipped.create(this, {
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/6428069&maxwidth=280&maxheight=280',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return {
                title: data.title,
                content: data.html
            };
        }
    },
    close: true,
    hideOn: false,
    skin: 'light',
    radius: false,
    position: 'topleft'
});
```

I tried my extension on Wikipedia and the bottom part of the page covered the upper half.

[image]

I have tried using the code based on the documentation just in a html page I created and it still did not work. I will post the html for this page soon.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've recently used tooltipster ( http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/ ) Check if You can achieve what You want with it.
Also joining @dreamweiver 's request - create a fiddle.

Comment: still looking for answers